# How do you get rid of converts in Idle Worship?

Tags: idle-worship

In the facebook game [Idle Worship](https://apps.facebook.com/idleworship/), how do you get rid of mudling converts on your island?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that you simply have to bless your mudling until its faith in the enemy god is past 0, then deconvert.